# Bash-like code completion in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, tab-completion, omnicomplete

I'm currently using superTab for completions in Vim. However, I'd like the completions to be more like bash. For example, if I'm typing

```
st
```

and the possible completions are

```
struct, string
```

I'd like it to be completed to

```
str
```

if I press tab, and ideally display a menu of possible completions.

Plugins are OK.

EDIT: completeopt+=menu, longest does most of what I want, but after the menu pops up and I narrow it down some, pressing tab again does a full completion instead of giving the next longest common prefix.

Comment: What does supertab do now that you don't like?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It completes to a full word, so pressing tab after "f" becomes "fugitive." I just found the "longest" option actually does just what I want; somehow I thought it completed to the longest possible word :/

Comment: Please don't post the identical question on multiple sites: http://superuser.com/questions/575085/bash-like-code-completion-in-vim

Answer (score 3):

```
:set completeopt+=longest
```

should do the trick.

A great resource for tweaking the completion is [Make Vim completion popup menu work just like in an IDE](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE).